# Incorrect version of PyTorch after installation

Tags: pip, pytorch

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJxTr.png)
Im installing PyTorch on Windows 11 with this command
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121`
But after installation turning out that versions installed for CPU, not for CUDA, as it was said in log. Surprisingly, torchaudio version is 2.1.0+cu121, but torch and torchvision as on the screenshot, so I cant use CUDA, maybe someone knows how to fix this

I already:

1. Changed Cuda version
2. Manual installed .whl
3. Reinstalled pytorch

UPD: I ran `pip3 list` and found out that it seeing it correct, but I dont know why it uses different versions in notebook

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart Jupyter Kernel and it all worked
*It's silly, but I found the solution 10 minutes after I asked question and after couple of hours of trying*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).